# Nest Js - How to generate a file and send it as a request response without saving the file locally?

Tags: javascript, file, nestjs

I have a task where I need to export a json to csv via an endpoint. When accessing the endpoint, the route should return the .csv file with the data. Is there a way to do this without having to save the file locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a [File Interceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload) on a route without specifying a storage option, the file will exist purely in memory and you will not need to save it to the disk.

I should warn however that if a uploaded file is very large, you can run out of memory. It's generally a better option to save to the disk as a temp file, then delete afterwards.

Comment: But in this case, the interceptor will only work when I'm receiving the request in my API, right? In my case, I need to receive a request, generate the .csv file and return as a result, without saving the file locally.

Comment: If you have the file as a file object in memory, you should be able to return a streamable file https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files

Comment: I'll read about it, thanks for the help!